# query with subquery and testing boolean result of this subquery fails

Tags: sql

I have following query

```
SELECT CDCREDITEUR
FROM sysadm_CREDITEUR
WHERE STATUS = 'A' 
  AND CDCREDITEUR = 'XXX' 
  AND CDCREDITEUR IN 
    ( SELECT CDCREDITEUR 
      FROM GROOTBOEKMUTATIES
      WHERE GROOTBOEKMUTATIES.BOEKJAAR = 2013 )
  AND CDCREDITEUR IN 
    ( SELECT CDCREDITEUR
      FROM CREDOPENPST
      WHERE CREDOPENPST.BOEKJAAR = 2013 );
```

I know that CDCREDITEUR exists in  CREDOPENPST and that is not exists in GROOTBOEKMUTATIES
yet i do get a result back.

I would think that true and false in the "IN" would result in a query that returns nothing.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Sure you're using the right column name in the query from `GROOTBOEKMUTATIES`? If it does not have a column called `CDCREDITEUR` this will be resolved from the outer query.

Comment: I would suggest posting results of subqueries with filter on CDCREDITEUR applied.

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4c74/1 . AND works perfectly. You must have a value in GROOTBOEKMUTATIES (SqlFiddle is on Mysql, but I don't expect AND and IN operators to change from one db to another)

Answer (score 0):

Try execute separately

```
SELECT CDCREDITEUR 
  FROM GROOTBOEKMUTATIES
  WHERE GROOTBOEKMUTATIES.BOEKJAAR = 2013
```

and

```
SELECT CDCREDITEUR
  FROM CREDOPENPST
  WHERE CREDOPENPST.BOEKJAAR = 2013
```

And see what result it returns